# What is the difference between range based loop and stringstream while extracting characters from a string

Tags: c++, c++17, stringstream, range-based-loop

consider a string like string s = "xyz123".

```
for(char ch : s)
    cout<<ch;
```

and stringstream like

```
char ch;
stringstream ss(s);
while(ss>>ch) 
    cout<<ch;
```

They both give the same solution. Is there any case where the two behave differently?
When should each be used.

Comment: Why do you think they do the same thing?  The first prints a string to standard output, one character at a time, and the second extracts characters from a stringstream.

Comment: Those don't look equivalent to me. I'd use a while loop for the second, the for loop just looks wrong.

Comment: @StephenNewell, yes that is true but they do use different methodology, but they seem to have the same outcome. I want to know the cases where the two might behave differently.

Comment: Setting aside for a minute the user of the `stringstream` isn't needed, at the core of a range-based for loop is simply the use of iterators over each of the objects in a container. Which in essence both of your snippets do. The semantics will be slightly different (and in the second case you are reading 2-characters per-iteration), but underlying it all will be some iterator going from `.begin()` up to `.end()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second one will skip any whitespace in the string. That's how `>>` works.

Unless skipping whitespace is actually a requirement the second version is also unnecessary. Why construct a new object just to iterate through a string when there are methods built into string for iteration.